# What can I move to RAM drive to have the system working faster?

Tags: hardware, filesystem, ram

Which files/directories can I move to RAM drive to have the system working faster?

I'm planning to upgrade my laptop's memory to 8GB soon, so I'll have some fast memory to use. How to configure the system to work optimal with this memory?

The next changes I consider next are:
- upgrading hard drive to SSD
- start using virtualization (I need Windows sometimes)

Edit:

Maybe I can sacrifice boot time, and copy some files to RAM drive during boot?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To mount `/tmp` `/var/log` and `/var/tmp` in RAM. Add these lines to the end of fstab to mount `/tmp` (temporary files) as `tmpfs` (temporary file system):

```
tmpfs /tmp     tmpfs defaults,noatime,mode=1777 0 0
tmpfs /var/log tmpfs defaults,noatime,mode=1777 0 0
tmpfs /var/tmp tmpfs defaults,noatime,mode=1777 0 0
```

Save, then: `sudo mount -a`

Reboot for the changes to take effect. Running df, you should see a new line with `/tmp`, `/var/tmp` and `/var/logs` mounted on `tmpfs`.

Note: all log files will be lost after a reboot, to back them up manually run this in terminal:

```
rsync -av /var/log/* ~/saved_logfiles
```

To move Firefox Cache Into RAM:

Type `about:config` in firefox address bar and click *I'll be careful,I promise!*.
Right click on blank area and create a new string value called:

```
 browser.cache.disk.parent_directory
```

Set its value to `/tmp`

Restart Firefox.

Comment: How can I automate this `rsync` command to run it on logout, system shutdown or hibernation?

Comment: **/var/tmp** should NOT be placed in **tmpfs**. See user95602's [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/198908/147496)

Answer (score 6):

As per the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard for Linux, **`/var/tmp` should NOT be placed in tmpfs**:

http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_2.3/fhs-2.3.html#VARTMPTEMPORARYFILESPRESERVEDBETWEE

> The `/var/tmp` directory is made available for programs that require temporary files or directories that are preserved between system reboots. Therefore, data stored in `/var/tmp` is more persistent than data in /tmp. Files and directories located in `/var/tmp` must not be deleted when the system is booted. Although data stored in `/var/tmp` is typically deleted in a site-specific manner, it is recommended that deletions occur at a less frequent interval than `/tmp`.

Answer (score 0):

There's not much from a default installation to put on a ramdisk, since it will be erased every time you boot. A ramdisk is only usable for temporary files.
So directories to run of a ramdisk I can think of are /var/run/ and /var/tmp/ (maybe /tmp). I do this on Mac OSX (RamFS: https://gist.github.com/931579).